# jPlayer CirclePlayer Multiple Instances

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, jplayer, multiple-instances

I'm wondering how to get multiple instances of jPlayer's circleplayer set up on a webpage. One will be playing an .mp3 encoded m3u stream and the other will be playing a static .mp3 file on loop.

Here's the webpage in development at the moment: [Linky McLinkLink](http://ovalbenchmark.webs.com)

Please ignore the styling, positioning and general state of the website other than the players, and the fact that the majority of it is just an image for now. I think it's probably better that I don't paste thousands of lines of code into this field so just view the source.

The red (orange?) player will be the one playing an .mp3 file, and the blue one will be the one playing a stream.

jPlayer have a [demo](http://www.jplayer.org/latest/demo-03/) on their website of multiple instance audio players working together, but they aren't the circle player which uses slightly different code. For the life of me I cannot work out what goes where, and I'm rubbish at javascript, so it's making it that bit harder.

From the demo page I essentially want player one and player three, but currently the problems are as follows:

- The orange player doesn't know what it's trying to play
- I don't think the nicely implemented play one/pause other feature of their demo is working, but I can't tell. There's no reason it should because I haven't written it to anywhere as I can't work out where.

Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

In their [repository](https://github.com/maboa/circleplayer) there's [index.htm](https://github.com/maboa/circleplayer/blob/master/index.htm) with two circular players. The problem with those, however, is that 'play' on one player raises 'pauseOthers' event [(circle.player.cs Line 99)](https://github.com/maboa/circleplayer/blob/master/js/circle.player.js#L99). So you'll have to tweak their sourcecode a little. I just removed lines 99-101 and it worked, needs further testing, however.